# Cannot upload data get xivelyclient.put returned -1

Tags: upload, arduino

Background:
I am trying to upload data from a simple on off sensor to learn the Xively methods. I am using an Arduino Uno with a WiFi Shield. I made some simple alterations to an example sketch from the Xively library to keep it very simple. I have read the documentation and the FAQ's plus searched the web. There was a similar question (Can't connect to Xively using Arduino + wifi shield, "ret = -1 No sockets available) and the answer was to reduce the number of libraries loaded. I'm using the same library list recommended in that post.I have also updated my Arduino IDE and downloaded the latest xively and HTTP library. The code compiles without error. I re-loaded my device on the xively website and got a new API key and number as well. Plus, I ensured the channel was added with the correct sensor name. I have also checked my router and ensured the WiFi shield was connecting properly.

Problem: I can't see the data on the Xively website and I keep getting the following error messages on the serial monitor from the Arduino:

xivelyclint.put returned -1

also, after several tries, I get "No socket available"

Question: Is there an problem with the code or is it something else?

Current Arduino code (actual ssid, password and API key and number removed):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <Xively.h>

char ssid[] = "ssid"; //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "password";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

// Your Xively key to let you upload data
char xivelyKey[] = "api_key";

// Analog pin which we're monitoring (0 and 1 are used by the Ethernet shield)
int sensorPin = 2;

// Define the strings for our datastream IDs
char sensorId[] = "sensor_id";
XivelyDatastream datastreams[] = {
  XivelyDatastream(sensorId, strlen(sensorId), DATASTREAM_INT),
};
// Finally, wrap the datastreams into a feed
XivelyFeed feed(feed no., datastreams, 1 /* number of datastreams */);

WiFiClient client;
XivelyClient xivelyclient(client);

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Starting single datastream upload to Xively...");
  Serial.println();

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = digitalRead(sensorPin);
  datastreams[0].setInt(sensorValue);

  Serial.print("Read sensor value ");
  Serial.println(datastreams[0].getInt());

  Serial.println("Uploading it to Xively");
  int ret = xivelyclient.put(feed, xivelyKey);
  Serial.print("xivelyclient.put returned ");
  Serial.println(ret);

  Serial.println();
  delay(15000);
}
```